# Why variable b don't change in the for-loop?

Tags: c, for-loop, pow

Hy, I want to understand why variable b don't change and when I print it always be as I defined (zero). What's wrong with my code??

With this code I want to find the max integer number (b) that is 10^b <= n (with n given and integer as well).

This is my code (It's written in c):

```
#include <stdio.h>                          
#include <math.h>

int lg (int n);                            

int main() {

 int a = 0;
 scanf("%d", &a);
 printf ("\nN=%d e M=%d\n", a, lg(a));

 return 0;
}

int lg (int n) {
  double b = 0.0;

  for (int i=0; i==n; i++) {
    if (pow(10, i) <= n) {
     double b = i;
    } else {
    }
  }
   return (int)b;
}
```

Comment: never or only once, depending...

Comment: @Ctx correct .. whoops

Comment: The for loop condition is wrong. I think you mean `i < n` or `i <= n` instead of `i==n`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us a few examples of input and expected output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're declaring a new variable named `b` inside your loop and setting it equal to `i`. Since that's a different scope, it's not the same variable as the `b` declared before the loop. Change the line

```
double b = i;
```

to

```
b = i;
```

Your loop condition is also set to `i==n;`. That means your loop will only run once if your input is 0. That should probably be `i < n;`.

Comment: But this is only 21...

Comment: I change the line you told me but nothing change

Comment: @DarkHelmet Check my edit. You need to change your loop condition too.

Comment: Oh my... I wanna write <= and I can't see that mistakes. THANKS to all guys

Answer (score 1):

There are two variables named b.  One whose scope is the function lg, and one whose scope is restricted to the if clause of the for loop.  You modify the latter, but return the former.  Using the keyword 'double' declares a new varaible.  This is a common source of error, and simply turning up the warnings on your compiler should alert you to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring "b" variable twice.The "b" variable initialized with 0.0 have scope within the function "lg". And the "b" declared inside if codition have limited scope to that condition only.
Also check the second parameter of for loop i.e "i==n". This is statement would be always true i.e "1" if the value of input ("n") is  not zero.

Answer (score 0):

Error 1: `i==n`: if you compare `i==n` in a for loop, that loop will only run a time.You must fix it into `i<n`

Error 2: You repeated a double type. You mustn't declare a variable b in a for loop because the variable b in that loop will disappear from the loop when it stop repeating.Thus, the value of the variable b in the for loop won't assign.

You must delete the `double` keyword in the for loop, the variable b will change.